# Assets audio player Can't play songs in release mode

Tags: flutter

I try to make a music player with flutter assets audio player. When I play a song in debug mode its work perfectly, but when I build an APK it dont play song and crash.

crash logs

> C:\Users\Administrator>adb logcat -b crash 03-08 17:19:08.725 30418
> 30418 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main 03-08 17:19:08.725 30418
> 30418 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.music, PID: 30418 03-08
> 17:19:08.725 30418 30418 E AndroidRuntime:
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module with the Main dispatcher is
> missing. Add dependency providing the Main dispatcher, e.g.
> 'kotlinx-coroutines-android' and ensure it has the same version as
> 'kotlinx-coroutines-core' 03-08 17:19:08.725 30418 30418 E
> AndroidRuntime:        at f.a.w1.p.a(Unknown Source:4) 03-08
> 17:19:08.725 30418 30418 E AndroidRuntime:        at
> f.a.w1.q.h(Unknown Source:55) 03-08 17:19:08.725 30418 30418 E
> AndroidRuntime:        at f.a.w1.q.b(Unknown Source:0) 03-08
> 17:19:08.725 30418 30418 E AndroidRuntime:        at
> f.a.w1.e.a(Unknown Source:16) 03-08 17:19:08.725 30418 30418 E
> AndroidRuntime:        at f.a.x1.a.a(Unknown Source:15) 03-08
> 17:19:08.725 30418 30418 E AndroidRuntime:        at
> f.a.x1.a.a(Unknown Source:5) 03-08 17:19:08.725 30418 30418 E
> AndroidRuntime:        at f.a.d0.a(Unknown Source:41) 03-08
> 17:19:08.725 30418 30418 E AndroidRuntime:        at f.a.a.a(Unknown
> Source:3) 03-08 17:19:08.725 30418 30418 E AndroidRuntime:        at
> f.a.d.a(Unknown Source:22) 03-08 17:19:08.725 30418 30418 E
> AndroidRuntime:        at f.a.c.a(Unknown Source:0) 03-08 17:19:08.725
> 30418 30418 E AndroidRuntime:        at f.a.d.a(Unknown Source:12)
> 03-08 17:19:08.725 30418 30418 E AndroidRuntime:        at
> f.a.c.a(Unknown Source:0) 03-08 17:19:08.725 30418 30418 E
> AndroidRuntime:        at c.a.a.a.g.a(Unknown Source:139) 03-08
> 17:19:08.725 30418 30418 E AndroidRuntime:        at
> c.a.a.a.b.a(Unknown Source:706) 03-08 17:19:08.725 30418 30418 E
> AndroidRuntime:        at d.a.c.a.i$a.a(Unknown Source:17) 03-08
> 17:19:08.725 30418 30418 E AndroidRuntime:        at
> io.flutter.embedding.engine.e.b.a(Unknown Source:57) 03-08
> 17:19:08.725 30418 30418 E AndroidRuntime:        at
> io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(Unknown
> Source:4) 03-08 17:19:08.725 30418 30418 E AndroidRuntime:        at
> android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method) 03-08
> 17:19:08.725 30418 30418 E AndroidRuntime:        at
> android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:336) 03-08 17:19:08.725
> 30418 30418 E AndroidRuntime:        at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174) 03-08 17:19:08.725 30418 30418
> E AndroidRuntime:        at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 03-08
> 17:19:08.725 30418 30418 E AndroidRuntime:        at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 03-08 17:19:08.725
> 30418 30418 E AndroidRuntime:        at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:491)
> 03-08 17:19:08.725 30418 30418 E AndroidRuntime:        at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:940)

onTap function

```
onTap: () {
        if (model.player.playerState.value == PlayerState.stop) {
          model.play(index);
        } else if (model.player.current.value.audio.audio !=
            model.allSongs[index]) {
          model.play(index);
        }
      },
```

play function

```
play(index) {
    player.stop();
    player.open(
        Playlist(
          audios: allSongs,
          startIndex: index ?? 0,
        ),
        loopMode: player.currentLoopMode,
        showNotification: true,
        notificationSettings: NotificationSettings(
            stopEnabled: false,
            seekBarEnabled: false,
            customPlayPauseAction: pause()));

    notifyListeners();
  }
```

build.gradle in android folder

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle in app folder

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.music"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: Do you have the crash logs? Can you share some code?

Comment: I added  a crash logcat and onTap function in Gesture detector and play function. Its work in debug mode, play songs , but not work in release mode

Comment: Can you also share you build.gradle file.

Comment: I added in android folder and app folder build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Your error log says :

> Module with the Main dispatcher is missing. Add dependency providing the Main
> dispatcher, e.g. 'kotlinx-coroutines-android' and ensure it has the
> same version as 'kotlinx-coroutines-core'

Have you tried to add those librarires ? https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines